# Variable Scope in c# confusion

Tags: c#

Reading MSDN about threads https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx i am having a confusion in the part of the code that has this:

```
public class Worker
{

    public void DoWork()
    {
        while (!_shouldStop) // #1 Like here.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("worker thread: working...");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("worker thread: terminating gracefully.");
    }
    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true; // #2 And here.
    }

    private volatile bool _shouldStop; 
}
```

How can a the variable _shouldStop be used before it is declared? Check #1 and #2 above.

Comment: Do you mean _declared_ or _initialized_?

Comment: Here is a related one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564699/does-the-order-of-declaration-matter-in-java-c-like-it-does-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can a the variable _shouldStop be used before it is declared?

C#, unlike many other languages in the C family, does not require that named entities be declared before they are used.  **Locals** must be declared before they are used, but classes, fields, events, properties, and so on, can be declared and used in any order.

C# also requires that locals be *assigned* before they are *read*, but other variables need not be assigned before they are read. Fields, array elements and so on, are assigned a default value when they are created.

Comment: Thanks eric BTW i am reading your book and Mark's Essential c# :)

Comment: @GeorgeOscStephan: You're welcome. Thanks for reading the book! I hope you enjoy it. It's been a lot of fun to work on it with Mark.

Comment: And as a followup question. Isn't the variable _shouldStop a local in this class or is it called a data member when it is in the class.

Comment: @GeorgeOscStephan: It is a *local* if it is declared inside a method, event, property, constructor, destructor, operator, and so on.  It is a *member* if it is declared immediately inside a type. Formal parameters can be thought of as a special kind of local.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Class variables can be declared wherever within the class. They also needn't be assigned an explicit value; they're automatically allocated as default(T) where T is their type